# Create a matrix with a set of ranges in columns and a set of ranges in rows with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, range, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame in which one column 'F' has values from 0 to 100 and a second column 'E' has values from 0 to 500. I want to create a matrix in which frequencies fall within ranges in both 'F' and 'E'. For example, I want to know the frequency in range 20 to 30 for 'F' and range 400 to 500 for 'E'.

What I expect to have is the following matrix:

[matrix of ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WR56.png)

I have tried to group ranges using pd.cut() and groupby() but I don't know how to join data.

I really appreciate your help in creating the matrix with pandas.

Comment: Can you show your code and what you have tried so we can help

Answer (score 0):

you can use the cut function to create the bin "tag/name" for each column.
after you cat pivot the data frame.

```
df['rows'] = pd.cut(df['F'], 5) 
df['cols'] = pd.cut(df['E'], 5) 
df = df.groupby(['rows', 'cols']).agg('sum').reset_index([0,1], False) # your agg func here
df = df.pivot(columns='cols', index='rows')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @usher! Your answer is right what I was working on. The pivot function is perfect to create the matrix!

Answer (score 0):

So this is the way I found to create the matrix, that was obviously inspired by @usher's answer. I know it's more convoluted but wanted to share it. Thanks again @usher

```
E=df.E
F=df.F

bins_E=pd.cut(E, bins=(max(E)-min(E))/100)
bins_F=pd.cut(F, bins=(max(F)-min(F))/10)

bins_EF=bins_E.to_frame().join(bins_F)
freq_EF=bins_EF.groupby(['E', 'F']).size().reset_index(name="counts")
Mat_FE = freq_EF.pivot(columns='E', index='F')
```